# Worker Role Unexpected error

Tags: json, azure, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to fetch some `JSON` data as a cron job(periodically) and store it to a *database*. So, I'm employing a worker role in `Azure`. But the `http requests` are failing. Here's the code:

```
 public override void Run()
    {
        // This is a sample worker implementation. Replace with your logic.
        Trace.TraceInformation("WorkerRole1 entry point called", "Information");

        while (count <= 10)
        {
            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            string download = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Kolkata&units=metric";
            string json = wc.DownloadString(download);



            var jObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json) as JObject;
            List<JObject> result = jObj["weather"].Children()
                  .Cast<JObject>()

                  .ToList();


            var final = result[0].Children()
                            .Cast<JProperty>()


                            .Select(x => new
                            {
                                temp = (string)x.Value,

                            }).ToList();


            var temp = jObj["main"]["temp"];
            var humidity = jObj["main"]["humidity"];
            var condition = final[2].temp;

            /*SQL insert query for weather data*/
            con.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO WEATHER(id,temperature,humidity,condition) VALUES(@id,@temp,@humid,@cond)", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", count);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@temp", Convert.ToInt32(temp));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@humid", Convert.ToInt32(humidity));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cond", condition.ToString());
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            Trace.TraceInformation("Working", "Information");
            count++;
  }
}
```

Please tell me what is the problem and provide me the solution....

Comment: What's the exact error you're getting?

Comment: I tried your code. It works just fine! What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: The Data is not being backed up in the database. I mean the insert query is not only working. Debugging shows error NullException which means JSON is not being fetched.. :( Although i was testing code on 127.0.0.1 not on production azure.